# Wait for asynchronous block before continuing

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a function lets call it "a" that runs some code and then returns a string "x" is updated in an asynchronous code block and then returned.

How would I go about making the program wait to return x until after the asynchronous code runs?

```
func a() -> String {

    //code
    //code
    var x: String
    async block {

    x = "test"
    }
    return x
}
```

Comment: Change async block to `sync`

Comment: by using a closure.

Comment: the question you have to ask yourself is, why to dispatch some code asynchronously (which should return immediately)  and then block the caller from execution until the result is available. You have to rearrange your code, don't waste your time to reinvent the wheel ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use completion closure for this

```
func a(completion: @escaping (_ value:String)->()) {
    var x: String = ""
    async block {
      x = "test"
      completion(x) //when x has new value
    }
}
```

//Call like this (value will be executed when the completion block is returned

```
a { (value) in
     print(value)
  }
```

Comment: Awesome response!!! I was trying to research how to use PromiseKit and then I found your solution which worked excellently. You're the man!

Answer (score 13):

Like everyone pointed out you can use a completion handler(`closure`) to perform the operation. But you can also wait for the asynchronous call to be completed using `DispatchSemaphore`. The semaphore obtains a lock when it makes `wait` call and it's released when it's signaled from the asynchronous block.

```
func a() -> String {
    var x = ""
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        x = "test"
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    semaphore.wait()
    return x
}
```

Comment: Today (2023) with the availability of `async/await` a semaphore is strongly discouraged because it blocks the thread.

Comment: Sometimes blocking the thread is specifically what you want to do.